# Bazel 3.5.1 version download

Tags: dockerfile, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a dockerfile:

FROM golang:latest

```
RUN apt update &&\
    apt-get install unzip &&\
    apt install -y default-jdk &&\
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python3.5

RUN go get github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk

COPY . /data
WORKDIR /data

ENTRYPOINT bazelisk run //src/python/io/app:main
```

I am getting the error:

```
**Downloading https://releases.bazel.build/3.5.1/release/bazel-3.5.1-linux-x86_64...

2020/09/29 07:30:41 could not download Bazel: HTTP GET https://releases.bazel.build/3.5.1/release/bazel-3.5.1-linux-x86_64 failed with error 404**
```

It is a version issue i think, how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The newest Bazel version is currently 3.5.0. Version 3.5.1 does currently not exist. "downgrade" to Bazel version 3.5.0.